# binary search tree recursive insert method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm studying `Java`, and I have some questions:

This is a `binary search tree` and I want to create the `insert` method. What is wrong with what I did?

I think `left` and `right` are `Node`, but I don't know how to use it because `Node` I know is like

```
public Node(int data, Node next)
```

What do I have to do?

```
public class BST {
private Comparable key;
private BST left, right;

public BST(Comparable key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

public boolean insert(Comparable key) {
    if (key.compareTo(this.key) < 0) {
        if (this.left == null) {
            System.out.println(key + " : insert success");
            this.left = left;
            return true;
        } else {
            insert(key);
        }
    } else if (key.compareTo(this.key) > 0) {
        if (this.right == null) {
            this.right = right;
            System.out.println(key + " : insert success");
            return true;
        } else {
            insert(key);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(key + " : insert fail");
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BST b = new BST("B");

    System.out.println("========== insert ==========");
    b.insert("G");
    b.insert("D");
    b.insert("K");
    b.insert("A");
    b.insert("D");
    b.insert("J");
    b.insert("H");
    b.insert("C");
    b.insert("A");
    b.insert("F");
    b.insert("E");
    b.insert("N");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not doing the insert correctly , when you find the position you need to create a new Node with the new key and make it the leaf, for example in your first check

```
     if (key.compareTo(this.key) < 0) {
    if (this.left == null) {
        System.out.println(key + " : insert success");
        this.left = new BST(key);
        return true;
    } else {
        return insert(key);
    }
```

you also need to check if the sent key is already inserted and return true.

Comment: there is java.lang.StackOverflowError in this.left = new BST(key);

Comment: yea you have couple of problems in your code, but this is the concept , i edited my code with some fixed